# DC christmas string lights without polarity

Tags: diodes, dc, polarity, lamp

My sister was doing an electronics project assigned from school and she was given sets of christmas light-looking bulbs in sockets with two wires sticking out of each. When she asked me for help ( it was a series vs parallel assignment), I first told her we'd have to figure out which ends of the bulbs were positive and which were negative, because she told me that the teacher showed them how to power the bulbs using a 9V battery.I know many christmas lights use AC, but these ones were powered from 9V DC just fine.

I was surprised to see that the bulbs worked in either orientation of the wires. That is, swapping the wires from positive to negative and back again both caused the light to turn on. How does this work? Everything I know about electronics says that LED's and such have a postive and a negative end, and you need to get it right for power to flow. I googled it and found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/534641) question, but he was still asking about AC lights. These are working just fine on DC. Anyone have any ideas? Is there some sort of polarity detection wizardry going on with diodes and such?
I left and forget to get pictures of the bulbs, but here is a picture from a video she sent of me with the lights working.

[image: depiction of strange bulbs]

Comment: From your picture, I suspect that those are incandescant bulbs, not LEDs.  Incandescant bulbs will work equally well on AC or DC.

Comment: have a very close look at one of the bulbs ... what do you see inside?

Comment: I was thinking one of [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDKFR.png). Incandescent, \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ and about \$170\:\text{mA}\$, or so. Maybe \$15\:\Omega\$? But saying they work fine off of a \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery makes me unsure. Can you try one with two AA batteries in series?

Comment: @periblepsis the incandescent lamps are available in different voltages ... the short christmas light strings use higher voltage bulbs

Comment: @jsotola Yes. 3.5 V is common. And I can't get around the fact that 9 V worked fine, either. But those in the green plastic base sure look like the 2.5 V ones to me. A thought. Not a conclusion.

Comment: These are bulbs BUT  LEDs could operate on either polarity if a bridge rectifier was hidden in the wiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not LEDs, they are just ordinary lamps. The filament will glow and pass current regardless of which polarity is used, and so they work with DC and AC.

Answer (score 0):

They are incandescent lamps but a little more special - equipped with a shunt that short-circuits them when they burn out.

[image: Christmas bulb]

So, when burn out, ordinary lamps represent an open circuit while these represent a short circuit. [The idea](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_did_my_Christmas_lights_burn_out) of ​​this clever trick from the past is that the light string will continue to work even if a lamp breaks (because the lamps are connected in series).

Comment: To a point... Each lamp that burns out raises the voltage on all of the others a tiny bit, increasing the chances that the next bulb will fail. Eventually the whole string goes in one big flash -- burning out both the filaments AND the shunts -- and you throw it away.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, This is exactly what happened to my light string in 2017...

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the light used, if you want polarity independence you can use something like this circuit, if you don't mind diode voltage drops
[image]